# Mysql update with joined data

Tags: mysql

I have this simple update query:

```
UPDATE
    erif_notify e
SET
    e.current_amount = '0.00'
    ,e._date = now()
WHERE
    id IN ( SELECT
                en.id
            FROM
                u_contracts uc
            JOIN
                erif_notify en
            ON
                en.contract_id = uc.id
            WHERE
                uc._status = 7
          )
```

But it gives me such error:

```
You can't specify target table 'e' for update in FROM clause
```

Why does it give me this?

I know I can just do it with two separate queries, but can it be done in one?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we go...this answer is tested and works:

**[SAMPLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/321e6/1)**

```
UPDATE
    erif_notify e
    INNER JOIN u_contracts uc
        ON e.contract_id = uc.id
        AND uc._status = 7
SET
    e.current_amount = '0.00',
    e._date = NOW();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need double subquery on this,

```
UPDATE
    erif_notify e
SET
    e.current_amount = '0.00' ,
    e._date = now()
WHERE
    id IN ( SELECT x.ID FROM 
              (
                 SELECT  en.id
                 FROM u_contracts uc
                      JOIN  erif_notify en
                         ON en.contract_id = uc.id
                 WHERE uc._status = 7
              ) x
          )
```

"The nested subquery in the `FROM` clause creates an implicit temporary table, so it doesn't count as the same table you're updating."

Comment: @Fluffeh sometimes, especially during delete. hehe

Comment: This seems to work, thanx a lot; but now I have a different problem. I get this warning if there are no IDs present: `expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given`. Any way to bypass it or should I just ignore it?

Answer (score 0):

Edit like this ans try

```
UPDATE
erif_notify as e
SET
e.current_amount = '0.00'
,e._date = now()
WHERE
id IN ( SELECT
            en.id
        FROM
            erif_notify en                
        JOIN
            u_contracts uc
        ON
            en.contract_id = uc.id
        WHERE
            uc._status = 7
      )
```

Comment: @Fluffeh I think he meant use 'as' clause with rest of the update query being same.

Comment: Hmmm, okay. Happy to give the benefit of the doubt, just always get jittery when a full query isn't given as an answer. What if the OP runs it?

Comment: @Gautam3164 As two previous comments said - your query (as is) will update **ALL** records in the table and this is **NOT** the intended result. Please update your answer - as it stands now it is **DESTRUCTIVE** (hopefully it is **NOT** your original intention)

Comment: Consider my edit friends,i just showed edited part as my ans.sorry for that

Comment: Nope, gave me the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I read your query couple of times and...
is not it identical to

```
UPDATE
    erif_notify e
SET
    e.current_amount = '0.00'
    ,e._date = now()
WHERE
    e.contract_id IN ( SELECT
                uc.id
            FROM
                u_contracts uc
            WHERE
                uc._status = 7
          )
```